# Cannot enable experimental in snap docker 19.03

Tags: docker, snapcraft

My docker is installed with [snap](https://snapcraft.io/).

I added the following line

```
$ sudo cat /root/.docker/config.json
{
        "experimental": "enabled"
}
$ cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
        "experimental": "enabled"
}
```

then `sudo snap restart docker`

then run the following commands

```
$ export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.11
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.12
 Git commit:        dd360c7
 Built:             Mon Jun  8 20:23:26 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.12
  Git commit:       77e06fd
  Built:            Mon Jun  8 20:24:59 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

**Experimental** is still `false`.  Please where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/docker-experimental-features/18127 it's possible to change the flag by editing `/var/snap/docker/current/config` and adding

```
"experimental": true
```

there.
It may be required to restart the snap with

```
sudo snap restart docker
```

afterwards.
Then calling `docker version` should print `Experimental: true`.

To be honest thought it hasn't really solved my personal issue, as calling `docker buildx` still ends with `docker: 'buildx' is not a docker command.`. It may be a bug, also noticed on the forum: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/docker-experimental-features/18127 .

I also tried installing a version from "edge" channel (19.03.15) and the problem persists. I'm afraid only using a non-snap version may end up being a solution for now.